# Photoshop script timestamp calculation

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

Using javascript, I like to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps.
The timestamp is generated from the new Date() method and is formatted as hh:mm:ss in military time. The time format hh:mm:ss makes it difficult to calculate the difference.

What needs to take place in order to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps?

```
function militaryTime() {
  // Get the time and format it  
  var digital = new Date();  
  var hours = digital.getHours();  
  var minutes = digital.getMinutes();  
  var seconds = digital.getSeconds();

  //military format 
  if (hours <= 9) hours = "0" + hours;
  if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
  if (seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;

  var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  return time
}

alert(militaryTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
var time1 = '11:27:00';
var time2 = '11:28:15';

var date1 = new Date('01/01/1970 ' +  time1);
var date2 = new Date('01/01/1970 ' +  time2);

var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);

console.log('difference = ' + diff / 1000 + ' sec'); // --> 75 sec
```